# Not able to reference an object field already declared

Tags: java, object, field, program-entry-point

I have an `Obstacle` class with a constructor for an Obstacle object:

```
public class Obstacle {

    public String obstacleType;
    public int obstacleSize, obstacleXCoord, obstacleYCoord;

    public Obstacle(String getType, int getSize, int getXCoord, int getYCoord){

        obstacleType = getType;
        obstacleSize = getSize;
        obstacleXCoord = getXCoord;
        obstacleYCoord = getYCoord;

    }
```

}

In another class, I import the `Obstacle` class and define a method, generateObstacle, creating a new `Obstacle` called `newObstacle`. I also make several references here to the fields of `newObstacle` that do not throw any errors:

```
public static void generateObstacle(){

    Obstacle newObstacle = new Obstacle(null, 0, 0, 0);

    //randomly generates a 1 or 0
    switch(spawnObstacle.nextInt(2)){

        //if 0
        case 0:
            //newObstacle type is tree
            newObstacle.obstacleType = "TREE";
            break;

        //if 1
        case 1:
            //newObstacle type is rock
            newObstacle.obstacleType = "ROCK";
            break;

    }

    //randomly generates 0, 1, or 2
    switch(spawnObstacle.nextInt(3)){

        //if 0
        case 0:
            //newObstacle size is 1
            newObstacle.obstacleSize = 1;
            break;

        //if 1
        case 1:
            //newObstacleSize is 2
            newObstacle.obstacleSize = 2;
            break;

        //if 2
        case 2:
            //newObstacle size is 3
            newObstacle.obstacleSize = 3;
            break;

    }

}
```

etcetera. However, inside my `main(`) method, I can't make a reference to any fields of `newObstacle` or `newObstacle` itself:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    spawnPlayer();

    while(runGame){

        switch((playerInput.nextLine()).toUpperCase()){

            case "W": 
                for(int x = 0; x < allExistingObstacles.size(); x++){

                    if(newObstacle.obstacleXCoord == currentXCoord){                        

                    }                       
                }
```

Referencing

```
newObstacle.obstacleXCoord
```

throws an error and says

> newObstacle cannot be resolved to a variable

Why can I reference Obstacle fields elsewhere in my code but not here?

Comment: Your ```main``` function does not declare the ```newObstacle``` variable (it is local to the ```generateObstacle```method.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `newObstacle` is limited to a function `generateObstacle()` so define

```
 static Obstacle newObstacle = new Obstacle(null, 0, 0, 0);
```

outside the function so that the reference(`newObstacle`) can be in global scope and can be accesible in any function on that class.

Also `newObstacle` should be `static` in order to be accesible inside static methods thanks to `@chrylis` for pointing this out.

Comment: It'll need to be static.

Answer (score 1):

it's because the instance exist only inside the scope of the method **generateObstacle**

```
public static void generateObstacle(){

    Obstacle newObstacle = new Obstacle(null, 0, 0, 0);
```

So outside this method the variable : newObstacle is not visible.

I guess you need to return this instance

```
public static Obstacle generateObstacle(){
  // ...
  return newObstacle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the object for `Obstacle` class inside the `generateObstacle()` . So the scope of the object is within the method .

You cant use it to refer the variable outside the block where its being declared

Answer (score 0):

In `generateObstacle` it works because you have `Obstacle newObstacle = new Obstacle(null, 0, 0, 0);` at beginning of method.

You `main` lack of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `newObstacle` in the `main` context has not been initialized.

You need to assign it to the result of `generateObstacle`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Obstacle newObstacle = generateObstacle();
    // ...
}
```

And your `generateObstacle` method should return the obstacle:

```
public static void generateObstacle() {
    Obstacle newObstacle = new Obstacle(null, 0, 0, 0);
    // ...
    return newObstacle;
}
```